# An adverb for algorithm

Tags: adverbs

There have been good questions asked and good answers given regarding the usage of various derivations stemming from the noun "algorithm". I have not seen, however, an adverb transition from the adjective "algorithmic". Most dictionaries do not even include the word "algorithmic".

Is "algorithmicly" a proper adverb formation of this word or is there some reason why it is not? With that question asked, no matter what its answer, one is led to consider why the lack of attention from dictionary publishers who undoubtedly must formulate inclusion in the dictionary by use of some algorithm.

Comment: Have you checked [algorithmically](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/algorithm)?

Comment: Can you give some usage examples?

Answer (score 2):

## Algorithmically

This seems like the most direct example as it is actually IN the Merriam-Webster dictionary, online version.

Directly from [Merriam-Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/algorithmically):

## algorithm

noun
al·​go·​rithm ˈal-gə-ˌri-t͟həm
: a procedure for solving a mathematical problem (as of finding the greatest common divisor) in a finite number of steps that frequently involves repetition of an operation
broadly : a step-by-step procedure for solving a problem or accomplishing some end
There are several search engines, with Google, Yahoo and Bing being the biggest players. Each search engine has its own proprietary computation (called an "algorithm") that ranks websites for each keyword or combination of keywords.
—Julie Brinton
… sometimes you solve a problem by coming up with an algorithm of some kind. But sometimes you solve a problem in a very ad hoc sort of way.
—William H. Huggins
algorithmic
ˌal-gə-ˈrit͟h-mik
adjective

### algorithmically (emphasis mine)

ˌal-gə-ˈrit͟h-mi-k(ə-)lē

##### adverb  (emphasis mine)

Some usage examples can be found in this article titled ["How to algorithmically generate an image dataset"](https://towardsdatascience.com/algorithmically-generated-image-dataset-71aee957563a), this article titled ["Algorithmically random sequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence) and this random book chapter titled ["Chapter 12: Thinking Algorithmically"](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Engineering/Introduction_to_Engineering/01%3A_Chapters/Chapter_12%3A_Thinking_Algorithmically)